# How can I view Garbage Collection logs?

Tags: apache-storm

I read that the Garbage Collection logs can be very useful for troubleshooting performance issues, but I'm unable to view them.

I added the below to my yaml, where the xloggc attribute is set to the same path where I can find my worker/supervisor/etc logs:

```
worker.childopts: "-XX:+PrintCGTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xloggc: /mycomp/log/storm/worker%ID%-jvm-gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=1M
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime"
```

And I added this to my code, to set the worker.childOpts for my topology:

`conf.put(Config.WORKER_CHILDOPTS, config.getWorkerChildopts());`

In the Storm UI, I can see that the worker.childopts are set correctly. But I can't find the GC logs in the specified directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you missing -XX:+PrintGCDetails?

Comment: Hi. I added this argument but still don't see the logs. I'm guessing it's an issue with the path? I see things like supervisor.log and worker-port#.log in `/mycomp/log/storm/`, it would make sense that this is where the GC logs would appear?

Comment: I do not have the conf.put() and have GC logs. Did you restart the supervisor? These options only apply to new workers. Did you restart/rebalance the topologies?

Comment: @gfelisberto, but did you specify your childOptd? What value did you use for path, just the absolute path where you see all your logs? I did restart the topology.

Comment: Just the:
-Xloggc:/var/lib/user/storm/storm/apache-storm-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT/logs/worker-%ID%-jvm-gc.log

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `topology.worker.childopts` instead.

Via: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/550/unofficial-storm-and-kafka-best-practices-guide.html